# Elements of a 1D array in C not showing after certain index

Tags: c, arrays

I'm a C beginner and I'm writing a program that basically converts a decimal number to base 6, but the numbers beyond the fifth position don't show up. 
When I input 56400 as the number I want to convert, the program's output is 13040 instead of 1113040, which is the correct answer.

I remembered the way java uses arrays, so I googled for a way of creating an array of dynamic size. I found that using alloc and malloc I could basically never run out space for my array. I didn't understand much of it because I haven't seen pointers and all that jazz and, in the end, didn't know how to implement it. So I decided to try different things:

First: The algorithm itself is out of the question. It can show a number whose number of digits don't exceed 5 and trying it yourself it basically gives the correct answer.
Second: I tried to define the size of the array to know if that was the problem. So I defined my array to have 8 elements and what happened was that if my decimal number gives a base6 one that has 8 digits the number shows correctly, if not, it gives really odd numbers like -7600 or -2 million-something.

Here's the code: my main method and my function that converts numbers to base 6, where I think the problem is.

```
/*Translations:
residuo: remainder
division: quotient of a division
adicion: sum, addition
numeroBase6: my number in base 6*/
int toBase6(int number) {
    int division = number;
    int residuo;
    int y = 1;
    int numeroBase6[y];
    int adicion = 0;
    int numSix = 0;

    residuo = division % 6;
    division = division / 6;
    numeroBase6[0] = residuo;
    while(division > 0) {
        residuo = division % 6;
        division = division / 6;
        if(division >= 0){ 
            numeroBase6[y] = residuo;
            y++;
        }else {
            numeroBase6[y] = division;
        }
    }

    for(int x = 0; x <= sizeof numeroBase6; x++) {
        adicion = numeroBase6[x] * pow(10, x);
        numSix += adicion;
    }
    return numSix;
}
```

My main method is:

```
        int num1;
    int resultado;

    printf("Escriba un numero en decimal: "); //Print "Write your decimal number"
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    resultado = toBase6(num1);
    printf("\nNumero en base 6 es: %d\n", resultado); //Print "Your number in base 6 is: "
```

So the thing I want to know is what can I do to show an array of numbers bigger than 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
int y = 1;
int numeroBase6[y];
```

You create an array of size 1, and the array will *always* be that size.  The size doesn't change just because the value of `y` changes.  As a result, you write past the end of the array with every digit after the first one.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The number of base 6 digits shouldn't be more than double the number of digits of a base 10 number, and a 32-bit int has at most 10 decimal digits, so just define your array to have 25 elements.  That should be enough to cover all possible values.

```
int numeroBase6[25];
```

Also, if you try to decimal-encode your base 6 number like this:

```
for(int x = 0; x <= sizeof numeroBase6; x++) {
    adicion = numeroBase6[x] * pow(10, x);
    numSix += adicion;
}
return numSix;
```

You could end up overflowing what an `int` can hold.  Rather that doing this, create the string representation directly and return the string.